# Using WMTS Stream in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, gis, esri

I am trying to write some OpenLayers javascript that can display a WMTS stream from a publicly available REST service located at: http://www.mchenrycountygis.org/arcgis/rest/services/2012aerials/MapServer

The problem I'm having is that while I am able to see OpenLayers generating Ajax requests to the endpoints, the tiles it is asking for do not exist. By playing around with the settings, I'm able to change these URLs somewhat, but I can't get the right combination of settings to actually generate valid URLs.

My current progress is documented in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v4WuW/2/

Code is also posted below

Any help would be appreciated!

```
/**
```

* I am trying to use OpenLayers 1.13.1 to consume a WMTS stream from here:
 * http://www.mchenrycountygis.org/arcgis/rest/services/2012aerials/MapServer
 */

var map = new OpenLayers.Map({
        div: "map",
        // QUESTION 1: This likely needs to be EPSG:102671 to match the WMTS stream. Why
        // does using the correct value completely break things?
        projection: "EPSG:900913"
    });

// matrixIds was extracted from capabilities.xml via OpenLayers.Format.WMTSCapabilities()
var matrixIds = [{"supportedCRS":"urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::102671","identifier":"0","scaleDenominator":545977.1577380951,"topLeftCorner":{"lon":-17463800,"lat":19496100},"tileWidth":256,"tileHeight":256,"matrixWidth":3,"matrixHeight":2},{"supportedCRS":"urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::102671","identifier":"1","scaleDenominator":272988.5788690476,"topLeftCorner":{"lon":-17463800,"lat":19496100},"tileWidth":256,"tileHeight":256,"matrixWidth":4,"matrixHeight":3},{"supportedCRS":"urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::102671","identifier":"2","scaleDenominator":136493.81696428568,"topLeftCorner":{"lon":-17463800,"lat":19496100},"tileWidth":256,"tileHeight":256,"matrixWidth":6,"matrixHeight":5},{"supportedCRS":"urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::102671","identifier":"3","scaleDenominator":68246.43601190475,"topLeftCorner":{"lon":-17463800,"lat":19496100},"tileWidth":256,"tileHeight":256,"matrixWidth":10,"matrixHeight":9},{"supportedCRS":"urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::102671","identifier":"4","scaleDenominator":34122.74553571428,"topLeftCorner":{"lon":-17463800,"lat":19496100},"tileWidth":256,"tileHeight":256,"matrixWidth":19,"matrixHeight":18},{"supportedCRS":"urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::102671","identifier":"5","scaleDenominator":17060.900297619046,"topLeftCorner":{"lon":-17463800,"lat":19496100},"tileWidth":256,"tileHeight":256,"matrixWidth":38,"matrixHeight":35},{"supportedCRS":"urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::102671","identifier":"6","scaleDenominator":8529.977678571428,"topLeftCorner":{"lon":-17463800,"lat":19496100},"tileWidth":256,"tileHeight":256,"matrixWidth":75,"matrixHeight":68},{"supportedCRS":"urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::102671","identifier":"7","scaleDenominator":4264.516369047618,"topLeftCorner":{"lon":-17463800,"lat":19496100},"tileWidth":256,"tileHeight":256,"matrixWidth":148,"matrixHeight":135},{"supportedCRS":"urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::102671","identifier":"8","scaleDenominator":2131.7857142857138,"topLeftCorner":{"lon":-17463800,"lat":19496100},"tileWidth":256,"tileHeight":256,"matrixWidth":295,"matrixHeight":271},{"supportedCRS":"urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::102671","identifier":"9","scaleDenominator":1065.8928571428569,"topLeftCorner":{"lon":-17463800,"lat":19496100},"tileWidth":256,"tileHeight":256,"matrixWidth":589,"matrixHeight":540},{"supportedCRS":"urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::102671","identifier":"10","scaleDenominator":566.9642857142857,"topLeftCorner":{"lon":-17463800,"lat":19496100},"tileWidth":256,"tileHeight":256,"matrixWidth":1107,"matrixHeight":1013}];

```
var wmts = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMTS({
    url: 'http://www.mchenrycountygis.org/arcgis/rest/services/2012aerials/MapServer/tile/{TileMatrix}/{TileRow}/{TileCol}',
    isBaseLayer: true,
    requestEncoding: 'REST',
    layer: '2012aerials',
    matrixSet: "EPSG:102671",
    matrixIds : matrixIds,
    style: 'default',
    /* QUESTION 2
    Ajax requests fire for incorrect tile URLs such as:       http://www.mchenrycountygis.org/arcgis/rest/services/2012aerials/MapServer/tile/0/27/29

    How do I fix this so we are requesting tiles that actually exist, such as:       http://www.mchenrycountygis.org/arcgis/rest/services/2012aerials/MapServer/tile/0/135/142

    Adding/Removing tileOrigin & tileFullExtent doesn't seem to help...
    */
    tileOrigin: new OpenLayers.LonLat(-17463800,19496100),
    tileFullExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(882499.9493310973, 1990000.0923467577, 1029999.9493310973, 2125000.0923467577),
    layers: ''
});                

map.addLayers([wmts]);
map.zoomToExtent([807168.3566418022, 2101119.5440438855, 1105331.5420203924, 2131750.0923467577]); // "initial" extent value
//map.zoomToExtent([882499.9493310973, 1990000.0923467577, 1029999.9493310973, 2125000.0923467577]); // "full" extent value
//map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(??, ??), 13);
```

Comment: QUESTION 1: This likely needs to be EPSG:102671 to match the WMTS stream. Why // does using the correct value completely break things? projection: "EPSG:900913" });  I'm not sure what you are asking here, but if you mean why can't you use EPSG:900913 with this WMTS service, then answer is simply because the WMTS service doesn't support it according to its GetCapabilities response (http://www.mchenrycountygis.org/arcgis/rest/services/2012aerials/MapServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml).

Comment: I see in your code that you have _matrixSet:"EPSG:102671"_ this I think is an error, there isn't a matrix set called EPSG:102671 in this WMTS.  I think you need to speciy eiter _default028mm_ or _nativeTileMatrixSet_ as the value.